# Heatmap amplitude zooming with mouse wheel

Tags: python, signal-processing, heatmap

I wish to control the zooming level via mouse wheel of the amplitude of a  2-D heatmap.

If you see the 2 screenshots below I have done the heatmaps in Matplotlib with imshow(). 
The thing is that I wish to control the color intensity (zooming on amplitude axis) with scroll up or down of mouse wheel. 
If Matplotlib is not capable of doing this any other plotting library in Python will also be helpful. 
Thanks for the support.

[Zoom Level without specifying Vmin and Vmax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv4Ua.jpg)

[Zoom LEvel spoecifying Vmin and Vmax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsxyr.jpg)